# Strange String Behavior Regarding to Numbers with Decimals

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, and you should be able to put in this "3[(Sqr)]+3[(Pnt)]+3[(Hex)]+3[(oct)]+3[(Cir)]+3[(Cbd)]+3[(Sph)]+3[(Ddc)]" in the textbox and get a result that finds a variaty of areas and volumes, those numbers all having "+" signs between them. However, it gives me a strange answer that looks something like this; "9+15.4842966052428.2742711206.90421193686507.097335529232543882308138.45584412271571.38268590217984400703+3+3+3+3+3+3". Does anyone know why this is happening? Again, the code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>PlayBox</title>
            <style>
                textarea {
                    resize: none;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100px;
                }
                body{
                    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
                    background-color: white;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <textarea id="input"></textarea>
            <button onclick="run()">Run</button>
            <p id="output"></p>
            <script>
                function run() {
                    var input = document.getElementById('input').value 
                    var simpPositive = input.search(/\[\D\i\m\p]/)
                    var doctorPositive = input.search(/\D\o\c\D\e\D/)
                    var shapePos = input.search(/\[\(\D\D\D\)\]/)
                    var defineVarPositive = input.search(/\[\D\=\d/)
                    if (shapePos > -1) {
                        var shapeReq = input
                        var sqredPos = shapeReq.search('Sqr')
                        console.log(sqredPos)
                        if (sqredPos > -1) {shapeReq = shapeReq.replace(shapeReq[sqredPos - 3], Math.pow(shapeReq[sqredPos - 3], 2))}
                        var pntPos = shapeReq.search('Pnt')
                        console.log(pntPos)
                        if (pntPos > -1) {shapeReq = shapeReq.replace(shapeReq[pntPos - 3], Math.pow(shapeReq[pntPos - 3], 2)*((1/4)*(Math.sqrt(5*(5+2*Math.sqrt(5))))))}
                        var hexPos = shapeReq.search('Hex')
                        console.log(hexPos)
                        if (hexPos > -1) {shapeReq = shapeReq.replace(shapeReq[hexPos - 3], Math.pow(shapeReq[hexPos - 3], 2)*((3*Math.sqrt(3)/(2))))}
                        var octPos = shapeReq.search('Oct')
                        console.log(octPos)
                        if (octPos > -1) {shapeReq = shapeReq.replace(shapeReq[octPos - 3], Math.pow(shapeReq[octPos - 3], 2)*(2*(1+Math.sqrt(2))))}
                        var cirPos = shapeReq.search('Cir')
                        console.log(cirPos)
                        if (cirPos > -1) {shapeReq = shapeReq.replace(shapeReq[cirPos - 3], Math.pow(shapeReq[cirPos - 3], 2)*Math.PI)}
                        var cbedPos = shapeReq.search('Cbd')
                        console.log(cbedPos)
                        if (cbedPos > -1) {shapeReq = shapeReq.replace(shapeReq[cbedPos - 3], Math.pow(shapeReq[cbedPos - 3], 3))}
                        var sphPos = shapeReq.search('Sph')
                        console.log(sphPos)
                        if (sphPos > -1) {shapeReq = shapeReq.replace(shapeReq[sphPos - 3], Math.pow(shapeReq[sphPos - 3], 3)*((4/3)*Math.PI))}
                        var ddcPos = shapeReq.search('Ddc')
                        console.log(ddcPos)
                        if (ddcPos > -1) {shapeReq = shapeReq.replace(shapeReq[ddcPos - 3], Math.pow(shapeReq[ddcPos - 3], 3)*((15+7*Math.sqrt(5))/4))}
                        shapeReq = shapeReq.replace(/\[\(\D\D\D\)\]/g, "")
                        if (simpPositive > -1) {
                            var shapeInput = shapeReq.replace('[simp]', '').replace(/(?<=[\d\)])\((?=\d)/g, "*(")
                            var simp = eval(shapeInput)
                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = simp
                        }
                        if (doctorPositive > -1) {}
                        if ((simpPositive < 0) & (doctorPositive < 0)) {
                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = shapeReq
                        }
                    }
                    if ((simpPositive > -1) & (defineVarPositive < 0) & (shapePos < 0)) {
                        var newInput1 = input.replace('[simp]', '').replace(/(?<=[\d\)])\((?=\d)/g, "*(")
                        var simp = eval(newInput1)
                        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = simp
                    }
                    if ((doctorPositive > -1) & (shapePos < 0)) {}
                    if (defineVarPositive > -1) {
                        var findMultVar = input.split('[')
                        var elem = findMultVar[1]
                        var fixFindMultVar = elem.substring(0, elem.length -1).split(';')
                        var replaceletter = input
                        for (i = 0; i < fixFindMultVar.length; i++) {
                            var replaceletter = replaceletter.split('[')[0].replaceAll(fixFindMultVar[i].split('=')[0], fixFindMultVar[i].replace(/\D\=/, ""))
                        }
                        if (simpPositive > -1) {
                            var newInput2 = replaceletter.replace(/(?<=[\d\)])\((?=\d)/g, "*(")
                            var simp = eval(newInput2)
                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = simp
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = replaceletter
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Also, I am not concerned about using eval. It is a private project.

Comment: why are you escaping EVERYTHING in the regex ... `\D` - you know that doesn't mean `D` ... but `Not a Digit`, right?

Comment: Yes, that is another problem I have been having, .search has been very inaccurate.

Comment: I do know that \D means not a digit, and it represents letters I could not use in the regex, like "s" for example.

Comment: By saying .search has been inaccurate, I mean when using words in quotation marks, like "input.search("doctor")" (this, by the way, is not currently usable, but will be in the future) being triggered by me using [(Oct)].